# WordCloud Python jupyter notebook not working

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, word-cloud

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900, height=600, random_state=21, max_font_size=110, background_color='ghostwhite', 
                      max_words=200,colormap='Dark2').generate(all_words)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

ERROR:
**AttributeError: 'TransposedFont' object has no attribute 'getbbox'**

It used to work before not it doesn't. Please advice.

Comment: Duplicate of [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76586062/8508004) if you used `pip` to install and not Anaconda/conda. Assuming duplicate unless you specify actual details enough for those trying to help you to be able to tell. Always say what kind of system and now installed things.

Comment: I installed via anaconda and i get error 
WordCloud.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900, height=600, random_state=21, max_font_size=110, background_color='ghostwhite', 
                      max_words=200,colormap='Dark2').generate(all_words)

Comment: I upgraded pip and Pillow and still doesnt work.

Comment: Did you restart everything after? Are you sure the upgrade was in the correct environment? The post I pointed to as a duplicate had the same issue and the solution from the other site worked. Potentially to get around this issue you could go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda), press 'launch binder' badge and then when the temporary session comes up, run in a new cell `%conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud` (based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wordcloud)). Restart the kernel and run your code (or complete example I provide as an answer).

Comment: I suspect you're on Databricks notebook, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

I have given an option to run it somewhere other than your own problematic system, see below.
Here is the minimal, **complete** reproducible example I used based on your incomplete block and [the post like yours from a few hours earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76586062/8508004):

```py
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
all_words = 'word1 word2 word2 word3 word3 word3'
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=900, height=600, random_state=21, max_font_size=110, background_color='ghostwhite', 
                      max_words=200,colormap='Dark2').generate(all_words)

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

---

The place and steps I suggested running that code above is described by [this comment I posted below the original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76592631/wordcloud-python-jupyter-notebook-not-working?noredirect=1#comment135056996_76592631):

> Potentially to get around this issue you could go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/conda), press 'launch binder' badge and then when the temporary session comes up, run in a new cell `%conda install -c conda-forge wordcloud` (based on [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/wordcloud)). Restart the kernel and run your code.